# Google Chart DataView calculated column using async data call values

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using a `DataView` calculated column. The `calc: callValue` function I’m using needs to get values from two asynchronous data call results, make calculations, and return a final value.

The way I have normally achieved multiple data calls and then calculating values is with `$.when().done()`.  However, the `DataView` is not waiting until the async calls finish and instead displays a null value.

I think it’s in the syntax but can’t figure it out.  This is what I have so far.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

view.setColumns([
  data.getColumnIndex('PART'),
  { calc:  callValue, type: 'string'}
]);

function callValue(dataTable, rowNum) {

   var part = dataTable.getValue(rowNum, dataTable.getColumnIndex('PART');
   var value1;
   var value2;

   $.when(
      $.get( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" ), 
      $.get( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" )
   ).done(function(json1, json2){
      value1 = json1[0].title;
      value2 = json2[0].website;
   })

   return part + value1 + value2;
}
```

How can I achieve my goal...get values from two asynchronous data call results, make calculations, and return a final value?

Thank you for any direction you can provide!

Comment: since `$.when` is async, the `return` statement will always run before `$.when` is finished. you'll need to collect all the possible data, before creating the data view...

Comment: Hi, I ended up doing exactly what you said: make the async call to get the info then use it in the dataView.  Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:  Call async data then use it in the `DataView`.  See comment from @WhiteHat.

> since `$.when` is async, the `return` statement will always run before
>   `$.when` is finished. you'll need to collect all the possible data,
>   before creating the data view... – WhiteHat Oct 18 at 1:26